# UK visit visa and financial statements as supporting documents

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I am applying for the UK visit visa to attend my college convocation. I am married and I do work but do not have a strong financial statement at this point. However I am traveling alone. Can I show my husband's bank statement that he is supporting me for this trip as he has a stronger one and will eventually be helping me?

Comment: There is no reason why not, especially if your husband is contributing to the cost of the trip. You will need to provide his pay slips too as evidence of the source of his financial support for you. Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If your husband is paying wholly or partly for your travel you should say so in the application.

You should include a statement from your husband that he will do so, and financial details for both you and your husband.